# buffer_with_count behavior is different on an interval observable than on a range observable. Why?

Tags: python, reactivex, rx-py

I am trying out [RxPy](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY) and I am not understanding this behavior for the `buffer_with_count` operator:

## Scenario 1: An interval observable

This one works as I expect.

### No Buffer

```
>>> Observable.interval(500).take(6).subscribe(print)
<rx.disposables.anonymousdisposable.AnonymousDisposable object at 0x104733d68>
>>> 0
1
2
3
4
5
```

### With Buffer (count=3)

```
>>> Observable.interval(500).take(6).buffer_with_count(3).subscribe(print)
<rx.disposables.anonymousdisposable.AnonymousDisposable object at 0x104789a20>
>>> [0, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
```

## Scenario 2: A range observable

This one doesn't produce the expected buffered output

### No Buffer

```
>>> Observable.range(0, 6).subscribe(print)
0
1
2
3
4
5
<rx.disposables.anonymousdisposable.AnonymousDisposable object at 0x1046ea160>
```

### With Buffer (count=3)

```
>>> Observable.range(0, 6).buffer_with_count(3).subscribe(print)
[1, 2]
[4, 5]
<rx.disposables.anonymousdisposable.AnonymousDisposable object at 0x1046ea710>
```

What's happening in this second scenario?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Might have been a bug which has since been fixed because I just tried your second scenario and it seems to works as it should..

```
>>> Observable.range(0, 6).buffer_with_count(3).subscribe(print)
[0, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
```